# Exploding BOM through recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query, ax

I'm trying to explode the BOM through recursive CTE, but I'm still getting the anchor rows only. However, I'm trying to use this SQL code:

```
With BOMTree_CTE

AS

(

--Anchor

Select 

B.BOMID

,B.ITEMID 

,B.LINENUM

,B.position

,B.BOMQTY

,B.INVENTDIMID

,0 as 'CurrentLevel'

,BV.BOMID as BVBomId

,BV.ITEMID 

FROM BOM B Left Join BomVersion BV On B.ItemID = BV.ItemId



Union All

Select 

BB.BOMID

,BB.ITEMID

,BB.LINENUM

,BB.position

,BB.BOMQTY

,BB.INVENTDIMID

,CurrentLevel+1

,CAST('1' as nvarchar(20)) 

,CAST('2' as nvarchar(20))

From Bom BB  Join BOMTree_CTE C On BB.BOMID = C.BVBomId

)

select * from BOMTree_CTE C
```

I don't wanna do it through X++, I need it through SQL!

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Common Table Expressoins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Well one thing you are missing is using DataAreaId and PartitionId (if using AX 2012 R2).
Take a look on the defined indexes.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly this... however I am unable to find a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently I found it, just used a stored procedure and passed the BOMId Parameter to the where statement of the Anchor CTE.